# Will the Database hustles if I update a field every 5 seconds?

Tags: database, database-connection, chat, offline, actionlistener

I am developing a web app which needs to check the internet if got connection or not.
If got connection, it will update a field in the db every 5 seconds.
Basically, it's a chat-like web app wherein it will update a field for datetime last seen online.
So that it will show on the other users who is currently online/logged in.

I will implement the snipplet in all the pages so that it will update the DB while you navigating the pages.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No self respecting database should have an issue with that.